# Error trying to access Neo4j database through REST for traversal using Gremlin

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, neo4j, gremlin

I am using Gremlin over Neo4j Database. I'm able to load the tinkergraph database and do gremlin traversal on it, but unable to load local-database and do the traversal on it.

From tinker graph on the console i'm using following commands and it works fine:

```
g = new TinkerGraph();
g.loadGraphXML('/db/data/graph-example-1.xml');
g.V.name    this works fine and getting the expected results.
```

Even from Java-code i'm able to do it. I send the same  command as:

```
final String scriptURI = SERVER_ROOT_URI + "ext/GremlinPlugin/graphdb/execute_script";
WebResource resource = Client.create().resource(scriptURI);
String entity = toJsonNameValuePairCollection("script", " g = new TinkerGraph();g.loadGraphXML('/db/data/graph-example-1.xml');g.V.name");
ClientResponse response = resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(entity .post(ClientResponse.class);
```

But when I try to access data from hard-disk that I have created at 'db/data/' it's working fine in console but not through the java code.

Console commands:

g = new Neo4jGraph('db/data/');
g.V.name

I'm getting the expected output.

But through the Java code I'm getting following error: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException

my java code is:

final String scriptURI = SERVER_ROOT_URI + "ext/GremlinPlugin/graphdb/execute_script";
    WebResource resource = Client.create().resource(scriptURI);
    String entity = toJsonNameValuePairCollection("script", "g = new                                            Neo4jGraph('db/data/');g.V.name");
    ClientResponse response = resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(entity .post(ClientResponse.class);

Answer (score 0):

in Neo4j Server, g is already bound to the server Neo4j graph instance, so you can directly use it (omit the g = new Neo4jGraph() in the REST call to the Gremlin plugin).

Finally, if you really need to open a new database, make sure the 'db/data/' in the script is pointing where you want it. It is a relative path and thus relative to the servers working dir. Maybe you can do first

dir = new File('db/data')
dir.getAbsolutePath()

and return that?